# How come $X^2$ is a physical function?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, dimensional-analysis, units

This might be a very dumb question.

When we use values that are lower then one in lets say, the expression for kinetic energy -  $\frac{1}{2}MV^2$, (for example $V=0.9\frac{m}{s}$ or $V=0.8\frac{m}{s}$), it seems as though the relation between the energy and velocity is different then when we use velocities greater than one.

Off course this is the property of squaring numbers, that if they are bigger the one the result will be bigger then the original number and smaller if the original is lower then one.

**physics dont care about what we define as "one" (in this case $1\frac{m}{s}$
), so why does it seems that way?**

Comment: The expression $0.81m^2s^{-2}$ is smaller than $0.9ms^{-1}$ is not meaningful as the two quantities have different units.

Comment: You could think of wherever '1' is defined as a crossover point. If it gets larger on one side and smaller on the other and is continuous, a crossover must exist where the number does neither. But that's math. In physics we have units as jacob said.

Comment: *it seems as though the relation between the energy and velocity is different then when we use velocities greater than one*  This is not the case.  The relationship is the same - the same formula applies.  I have no idea what you are confused by.

Comment: $v^2$ is still a strictly increasing function, it also makes sense since $v$ and $-v$ should give the same kinetic energy